# Cannot connect to fast api server at localhost:8000 from my application which is running under a docker container

Tags: python, connection, fastapi

I a newbie to working with fastapi. I have a main.py inside docker container.When I connect to fastapi using

```
uvicorn main:app —-reload
```

from my container.I am prompted to connect to http://127.0.0.1:8000. On copying the address to Firefox I am getting the error:

```
 unable to connect.
```

How can I connect to fastapi server ?

P.S The git branch I am working from was developed by another colleague so I have little to no idea how was fastapi was set up inside the docker

Comment: Review the official documentation about the Deployments on Docker, provided by FastAPI  [Deploy with Docker](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/deployment/docker/)

Comment: Future readers might find [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75041731/17865804) helpful as well.

Answer (score 32):

You need to use the command

```
uvicorn main:app --reload --host 0.0.0.0
```

Your docker container is like a computer, which is independent. Thus it does not allow access from external sources. With the `--host` option, you allow external connections (outside of localhost from the point of view of the container). Basically, docker's localhost is different from your computer's localhost.

Comment: I also tried connecting to 172.18.0.2 which is the IP address of my container but that's not working too.

Comment: Can you post the `Dockerfile` ?

Comment: [uvicorn.org](https://www.uvicorn.org/) documents the python argument to specify the host `uvicorn.run("example:app", host="0.0.0.0", port=5000, log_level="info")`

Answer (score 0):

A workaround solution. Through on deploy app will have public address and webdriver.Remote can take it, in dev it is ok to run selenium locally.

## test_my_web.py

```
import unittest

from selenium import webdriver
import os

from dotenv import find_dotenv, load_dotenv
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

load_dotenv(find_dotenv())



class TestWebListAll(unittest.TestCase):
    def setUp(self) -> None:
        chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
        if os.environ.get("LOCAL_DEV"):  # == 'True'
            self.url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
            self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
        else:
            self.driver = webdriver.Remote(
                command_executor='http://localhost:4444',
                options=chrome_options
            )
            self.url = 'insert public addres'  #

    def tearDown(self) -> None:
        self.driver.quit()

    def test_(self):
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        print(self.driver.title)
```

Answer (score 0):

You also need to make sure that your port mapping is correct.

1. In the Dockerfile:

`CMD ["uvicorn", "main:app", "--host", "0.0.0.0", "--port", "80"]`

The host is set to 0.0.0.0, which is accessible locally as localhost (127.0.0.1 for most).

2. In the docker commands:

```
docker build -t myfastapi

docker run --name mycontainer -p 8000:80
```

This will map your local port 8000 to docker's 80.

So now, you should be able to access your server at localhost:8000

Hope this helped!

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to check "is your container up?"

```
docker ps -a
```

Then if some pods are not active, you should check the logs of container.

```
docker logs {container-id}
```

[image]

I changed my dockerfile with your CMD part and ran it. It worked successfully. But I noticed that you are using

```
docker run --name mycontainer -p 8000:80
```

Maybe you should try that:

```
docker run --name mycontainer -p 8000:80 <docker image id>
```