# FastAPI listen to outbound port

Tags: linux, docker, tcp, debian, fastapi

I have a FastAPI docker running on my debian 9 server with `--net=host` running on port `8000`. I would like to make the FastAPI service open to the public, but do not know really how.
I can do `curl localost:8000/test` and will see the return but when I do `curl domain:8000/test` it will respond `connection refused`.

I have opened the port `sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 8000 -j ACCEPT` but still not seeing anything.
Do I have to configure `uvicorn` somehow to resolve the domain internally, similar  to what apache does with virtual hosts?

```
netstat -tulpn
(Not all processes could be identified, non-owned process info
 will not be shown, you would have to be root to see it all.)
Active Internet connections (only servers)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State       PID/Program name
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8000          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      -
```

```
sudo ss -tulpn                                                    
Netid State      Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address:Port                Peer Address:Port
tcp   LISTEN     0      128        127.0.0.1:8000                           *:*                   users:(("gunicorn",pid=44998,fd=5),("gunicorn",pid=44983,fd=5))
```

or should this rather return `0.0.0.0:8000` because I can ssh into the host no problem?

Dockerfile

```
FROM tiangolo/uvicorn-gunicorn-fastapi:python3.9-alpine3.14

COPY ./app /app

USER root

COPY ./requirements.txt /requirements.txt
RUN apk add py3-pip && \
    pip install --upgrade pip

RUN apk add --no-cache mariadb-connector-c-dev ;\
    apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps \
        build-base \
        mariadb-dev ;\
    pip install -r /requirements.txt;\
    apk del .build-deps 

ENV HOSTNAME fastapi
ENV PYTHONPATH '/:/app'
COPY ./gunicorn_conf.py /gunicorn_conf.py
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68205999/771578 should help you.

Comment: Can you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: I can access it through localhost:8000 @messivanio . Dockerfile in main post^^^

Answer (score 1):

since you can access FastAPI from your host machine, that means docker port mapping works just fine.
what is left is to add the hostname to the origins in the Router.py module
something like this \

```
origins = [
    "http://127.0.0.1:8000",
    "http://localhost:8000",
    "http://yourhostgoeshere:yourport",

]

app.add_middleware(
    CORSMiddleware,
    allow_origins=origins,
    allow_credentials=True,
    allow_methods=["*"],
    allow_headers=["*"],
)
```

remember to change HTTP to HTTPS if you don't have a  proxy.

Comment: cool, I'll look into that!